# Error "TerminatorExpectedAtEndOfString" when execute a powershell code from a batch file?

Tags: command-line, powershell, batch, batch-file, screenshot

I want to execute a powershell code with a batch file to take a screenshot from my desktop that i found it here [Take a Screenshot of a User’s Desktop with PowerShell](http://woshub.com/take-user-desktop-screenshot-with-powershell/#h2_1).

So,When i execute it as powershell script it works without any error and works for me 5/5 but when i take it as batch file like this i got this type of error that i don't know how to debug it correctly ?

`Error "TerminatorExpectedAtEndOfString"`

So if someone can explain me why and where this error comes from ?

Here is my batch code :

```
@echo off
Title Get a ScreenShot with Batch and Powershell
Call :ScreenShot
pause
::----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
:ScreenShot
Powershell ^
$Path = "E:\ScreenCapture\";^
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms;^
$screen = [System.Windows.Forms.Screen]::PrimaryScreen.Bounds;^
$image = New-Object System.Drawing.Bitmap($screen.Width, $screen.Height);^
$graphic = [System.Drawing.Graphics]::FromImage($image);^
$point = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(0,0);^
$graphic.CopyFromScreen($point, $point, $image.Size);^
$cursorBounds = New-Object System.Drawing.Rectangle([System.Windows.Forms.Cursor]::Position,[System.Windows.Forms.Cursor]::Current.Size);^
[System.Windows.Forms.Cursors]::Default.Draw($graphic, $cursorBounds);^
$FileName = (Get-Date -F dd-MM-yyyy_HH_mm_ss)+".jpg";^
$FilePath = $Path$FileName;^
$FormatJPEG = [System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat]::jpeg;^
$image.Save($FilePath,$FormatJPEG)
Exit /B
::------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: save the PoSh code as a file & then use powershell.exe in the BAT file to load that file. take a look at `powershell.exe /?` - especially the `-File` parameter.

Comment: Thank you for this suggestion, but i want to learn where this error comes from  exactly?

Comment: the easiest way is to test each line until you find the source. i see that Theo has done that work for you, tho. [*grin*]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

May be you need:

1. Use `^` in `)`
2. Replace `"` to `'` in  `$var='value'`
3. Use To.String in `$((Get-Date).ToString('dd-MM-yyyy_HH_mm_ss')+'.jpg')`

---

Test it in your command line:

```
Powershell $Path='E:\ScreenCapture\'; Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms;$screen = [System.Windows.Forms.Screen]::PrimaryScreen.Bounds;$image = New-Object System.Drawing.Bitmap($screen.Width, $screen.Height^);$graphic = [System.Drawing.Graphics]::FromImage($image^);$point = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(0,0^);$graphic.CopyFromScreen($point, $point, $image.Size^);$cursorBounds = New-Object System.Drawing.Rectangle([System.Windows.Forms.Cursor]::Position,[System.Windows.Forms.Cursor]::Current.Size^);[System.Windows.Forms.Cursors]::Default.Draw($graphic, $cursorBounds^);$FileName = $((Get-Date^).ToString('dd-MM-yyyy_HH_mm_ss'^)+'.jpg'^);$FilePath = $Path+$FileName;$FormatJPEG = [System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat]::jpeg;$image.Save($FilePath,$FormatJPEG^)
```

Test it in your bat file:

```
@echo off
Title Get a ScreenShot with Batch and Powershell
Call :ScreenShot
pause 
goto :eof
::----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
:ScreenShot
Powershell $Path='E:\ScreenCapture\';^
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms;^
$screen = [System.Windows.Forms.Screen]::PrimaryScreen.Bounds;^
$image = New-Object System.Drawing.Bitmap($screen.Width, $screen.Height^);^
$graphic = [System.Drawing.Graphics]::FromImage($image^);^
$point = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(0,0^);^
$graphic.CopyFromScreen($point, $point, $image.Size^);^
$cursorBounds = New-Object System.Drawing.Rectangle([System.Windows.Forms.Cursor]::Position,[System.Windows.Forms.Cursor]::Current.Size^);^
[System.Windows.Forms.Cursors]::Default.Draw($graphic, $cursorBounds^);^
$FileName = $((Get-Date^).ToString('dd-MM-yyyy_HH_mm_ss'^)+'.jpg'^);^
$FilePath = $Path+$FileName;$FormatJPEG = [System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat]::jpeg;^
$image.Save($FilePath,$FormatJPEG^)
```

Answer (score 2):

The error comes from this line:

```
$FilePath = $Path$FileName;^
```

You should not concatenate variables to form a file path like that.
It *would* work if you surround it with double-quotes like this: `$FilePath = "$Path$FileName";^`, but far, FAR better is to use the [Join-Path](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/join-path) cmdlet:

```
$FilePath = Join-Path -Path $Path -ChildPath $FileName;^
```

or if you rather use .Net directly:

```
$FilePath = [System.IO.Path]::Combine($Path, $FileName);^
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but i don't know why none of those does not worked for me ? but this work 5/5
`Powershell -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -C ".\ScreenShot-PS.ps1"`
So my problem is not solved yet !

Comment: @Hackoo use `-File` instead of `-Command`

Comment: No problem for those two commands they worked `Powershell -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File ".\ScreenShot-PS.ps1"` or `Powershell -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command ".\ScreenShot-PS.ps1"` works 5/5, but i have a feeling this comes from Enconding or something from the parser of my console command line ?? still searching for it !
Can you please edit your post and send me the whole code that worked for you! thank you !